# After using `fill()`, why did the fields set still reported `null` value in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: fill, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can't the value filled by `fill()` command be included in the same calculation SQL statement in Apache IoTDB? I used the SQL statement with `fill` and try to do calculation based on certain data, and the result seems to be still `null` for the data points that I already set to use `fill`. Anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, the execution order of `fill` is relatively late. For example, for this statement `select s1+s2 from root.db.d1 fill(previous)`, IoTDB will first calculate `s1+s2` and then execute `fill` according to the calculation result. If you want to get the result after `fill`, you can just execute `show results` again.